# Parallel Jobs in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, informatica

Informatica pmcmd : is a command to invoke a Informatica Workflow .

My Script has multiple pmcmd commands which are executed one by one as script goes.
My workflows are not dependent on each other so I can execute them in parallel,

Can anybody tell me if there is any way I can submit all the pmcmd commands at the same time to invoke all my workflows from a single script.

Structure of my script is something like :

---

```
pre load checks
pmcmd ---1;
pmcmd ---2;
pmcmd ---3;
Success mail
```

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: `pmcmd1 &; pmcmd2 &; pmcmd3 &; wait; echo success`

Comment: @devnull, the `;` are redundant

Comment: @WilliamPursell True, in this case those were inserted to denote end-of-line markers!

Comment: To clarify, even as a one-liner, the `;` are not necessary.  The `&` acts as a separator just as the `;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can run them in parallel by adding a `&` at the end of each `pmcmd` command. This will run them in the background in a subshell.

Then use `wait` to wait for the background processes to complete.

```
pmcmd [first command args] &
pmcmd [second command args] &
pmcmd [third command args] &
wait
[mail command]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call each process with `&` at the end, this will bring the progress to the background.
The `wait` command will wait until all processes have been ended.
Something like this:

```
pre load checks

pmcmd ---1; &

pmcmd ---2; &

pmcmd ---3; &

wait

Success mail
```